# How do i manage 2 sidenav on single button click event in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

```
<button mat-icon-button><mat-icon (click)="drawer.toggle();">menu</mat-icon></button>
```

**As you can see the drawer.toggle() function which is called using click function. but my requirement is to call**

> drawer.toggle() on first click

and

> on second click is to call drawer2.toggle()

**I am not getting how to do that.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) and get a reference to your drawers.

In your template:

```
<button mat-icon-button (click)="handleClick();><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
<my-drawer-one #myDrawerOne></my-drawer-one>
<my-drawer-two #myDrawertwo></my-drawer-two>
```

In your component:

```
import { ViewChild, ... } from '@angular/core';

...
@ViewChild('myDrawerOne') drawer;
@ViewChild('myDrawerTwo') drawer2;

private clickCount: number = 0;

public handleClick(): void {
   this.clickCount++;
   if(this.clickCount === 1) {
      this.drawer.toggle();
      return;
   }

    this.clickCount = 0; // reset clickCount if necessary
    this.drawer2.toggle();
}
```

Simplified you could do it like this.